# Changing Background color of Image view in JavaFX8

Tags: javafx-8

i have tried to change the `ImageView` background color using CSS bt could n't change it...

How can i set my `ImageView` Background color in Javafx8 ?

Can any one help me out?

Here is my screenshot: [image: screenshot]

i want to replace the Gray background of the image with **Black** .

Comment: Can you show us a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which you have tried

Comment: i have tried this : **imageView.setStyle("-fx-background-color: BLACK");**

Comment: Do you want to set background color to ImageView or the Screen ?

Comment: I want to set background color to ImageView .

Comment: add an image/snippet to depict your problem, as this is insufficient data..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well it seems you need to add background color to your `Screen` instead of `ImageView`

Here is a working code and the output as well

```
public class ImageViewBackgroundColor extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        try {
            stage.setWidth(Screen.getPrimary().getBounds().getWidth());
            stage.setHeight(Screen.getPrimary().getBounds().getHeight());
            BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
            Image image = new Image(getClass().getResource("huskar.jpg")
                    .toString());
            imageView.setImage(image);
            imageView.setStyle("-fx-background-color: BLACK");
            imageView.setFitHeight(stage.getHeight());
            imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);
            imageView.setSmooth(true);
            imageView.setCache(true);
            borderPane.setCenter(imageView);
            Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane, Color.BLACK);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**Output**

[image]